Draw this please
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1.5pt]
\draw (2,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,3) -- (0,3);
\draw (0,3) .. controls (0,2) and (1,.5) .. (2,0);
\node[red] at (3,1.5){\Huge$fBA$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


If you are looking for an online service to compile your code, try https://texlive.net/ . If that's not why you posted this question, please clarify what problem you face.

Please clarify your question. Did you forget to compile?
